# mod_rewrite чпу

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Есть ссылка /message/?name=bublik

Надо чтобы ссылка была /message/bublik

Пробовал так, но не вышло: 
RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule ^message/([^/\.]+)/?$ /message/?name=$1 [L]
```

ну и так тоже не вышло

```
RewriteRule ^message/([^/\.]+)/?$ /?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `.htaccess` где лежит?

Comment: в корне лежит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^message\/([a-zA-Z]+)\/?$ /message/?name=$1 [L]
```

Правило в вашем случае будет таким, ваше неработало во первых т.к. не екранировались слеши, но главное у вас глупости написаны здесь `([^/\.]+)`

Comment: По-прежнему не заработало

Comment: Правило написано правильно, разбирайтесь...

Comment: Не правильно, нужно наоборот, из GET в ЧПУ.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы зайдя /message/bublik брать реквестом name и понимать что это бублик :) и наоборот. пока это никак не сработало

Comment: @Dem чета вы не в теме вообще, зачем писать о том в чем вы noob?:)Вы ваабще а чем?<br>
По теме - правило рабочее. Я так подозреваю что у вас в папке `/message/` лежит `index.php`? Если да то попробуйте написать полностью, т.е. добавьте index.php... Больше вариантов у меня нет, если вам реально принципиально разобраться - добавляемся в скайп<br>alexwindhope<br> и там решаем вашу проблему...

Comment: То, что я не правильно понял задачу - не делает меня нубом. Заработался, ошибся, бывает.

Comment: Ну удалили бы коммент тогда и небыло бы никаких притензий :)